# Change the position of index bar in UITableView in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7, tableview

In iOS 7 the index bar of a tableview is closer to the edge than before. If i try to loop through all subviews of the tableview and change the position and all subviews the index bar still is in the same position. If I change the position of the tableview the index bar moves.

So my question: **How do you change the position of the index bar in iOS 7 when it doesn´t seem to be a subview of it´s own?**